# This connector is used in a Remote car's key, somone knows which connector is this?

Tags: connector

This connector is used in a Remote car's key.

Adding information requested: Pitch 1mm
I Added the female connector too

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: female 1]

[image: female 2]

(click for larger images)

Comment: Need some pitch dimensions

Comment: (in other words, go get a ruler or a caliper and measure out some dimensions, i.e. width, length, etc.)

Comment: The pitch is 1.0mm